# dom4j : Replacing element

Tags: java, dom4j

I have the following XML :

```
<root>
<para>My paragraph with my <photo>MyPhoto</photo>
</para>
</root>
```

and I want to replace an element `<photo>MyPhoto</photo>` by this `<name>MyName</name>`

I use dom4j in my project :

```
List myPhotoToRemove = doc.selectNodes("//photo");
for(Object o : myPhotoToRemove){
    o = DocumentHelper.createElement("name");
    ((Element)o).setText("MyName"); 
}
```

It creates an element `<name>` without parent

Comment: Hello, provide some code of what you tried if you expect some help

Comment: You have a really good wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
List<Node> myPhotoToRemove = doc.selectNodes("//photo");
for(Node node : myPhotoToRemove){
    node.setName("name");
    node.setText("MyName"); 
}
```